# Custom sorting in Unix

Tags: shell, sorting, unix

I want to sort the following data in a particular order. I tried sort in different way but couldn't find any solution. please help. I am a newbie in Unix.:(

Data:-

```
method1:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method1:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method2:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method2:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method4:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method4:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method1:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method1:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method5:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method5:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
```

Desired output:-

```
method1:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method1:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method1:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method1:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method2:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method2:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method3:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method4:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method4:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method5:entry:2013.09.18.19.18.30
method5:exit:2013.09.18.19.18.30
```

The sorting should be based on method name and 'entry-exit' occurrence.

Comment: How do you know which `method1:exit` should be placed after a `method1:entry`? Both `method1:exit`s are identical. The same is true for `method1:entry` itself. You just want to match pairs of `entry` and `exit`s which have same `method` name?

Comment: @moghaddam: Yes, I want to just pair entry and exit with same method name.

Comment: I Think there is no way to do this directly in shell using commands and utilities (like `sort`, `set` or `awk`). You have to write some python or perl scripts to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you simply want to sort by method name, which is the first colon-delimited field.

```
sort -t: -s -k1,1 file.txt
```

The `-s` flag (stable sort) prevents `sort` from modifying the relative order of lines with the same first field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
sed -e 's/:/ /g' file.txt | sort |
awk 'BEGIN { var_entry="entry"; var_exit="exit"; flag="entry" }
    { if (flag == $2 && var_entry ==$2 ){
        i = 0; flag=var_exit; }
      else if (flag == $2 && var_exit == $2 ){
        i = 0; flag=var_entry; };
      i++ ; print i, $0 }' |
sort -t" " -k 2,2 -k 1,1 | sed 's/^[0-9]* //g'
```

The logic behind this is :

1. `sed -e 's/:/ /g`  replaces `:` with a space so the delimiters are consistent.
2. `sort` simply sorts on `method1` column.
3. `awk` step appends another column so that we can sort on that column so that we have a pattern like `entry exit` for matching `method1`, output is :

   1 method1 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method1 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method1 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method1 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method2 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method2 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method3 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method3 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method3 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method3 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method4 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method4 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method5 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method5 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
4. `sort -t" " -k 2,2 -k 1,1` : then we `sort` on `method1` column (2nd column) and if there are conflicts we resolve them on the newly added column viz. 1st column. output is :

   1 method1 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method1 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method1 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method1 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method2 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method2 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method3 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method3 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method3 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   2 method3 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method4 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method4 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method5 entry 2013.09.18.19.18.30
   1 method5 exit 2013.09.18.19.18.30
5. `sed 's/^[0-9]* //g'` : we remove the extra column which was created.

Comment: @snyder.The output is coming as a single line in your code. Is there any way can I get the output in different lines?  wc -l filename is returning 1.

Comment: @anz try this `cat file.txt | sed 's/method/\nmetthod/g'`

Comment: method name won't be constant, it can be some other name also.

Comment: @anz I have tested the above command on my shell, it gives newline. I am using bash, which shell are you using ?